# Error al eliminar un datos en arrayList iterando en Java

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo un pequeño problema a la hora de borrar un elemento de mi arraylist.

El ejercicio en si, pide que se haga con iterador.

ArrayList creado e Iterator:

```
 private ArrayList<Articulo> coleccion = new ArrayList();
 Iterator<Articulo> iter = coleccion.iterator();
```

Al meter el código del producto me salta a la exception configurada "Error"

Borrar articulo

```
public String borrarArticulo() {
        String codigo = null;
        Iterator<Articulo> iter = coleccion.iterator();

        try {

                System.out.println("Por favor introduzca el codigo del articulo");
                codigo = teclado.nextLine();
                ValidarCodigo(codigo);

            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                if (iter.next().getCodigo().equals(codigo)) {
                    iter.remove();
                    System.out.println("Producto eliminado");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }
        return codigo;
    }
```

La solución del ejercicio en si, es meter el iterador dentro del metodo. Así si que borra el articulo. Con iterador también se pueden borrar objetos de la ArrayList. Gracias a todos por atenderme. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Cuál es la excepción que te da? (El valor de la variable `e`) ¿Y qué es tu variable `teclado`? No la veo declarada por ningún sitio.

Comment: No hay valor de variable e, de exception se declara ahi, siempre funciona. La variable teclado es la de scanner, Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);. La excepción que me da es el error del catch

Comment: Me da que tu problema viene porque intentas eliminar un elemento a la vez que recorres su iterador. Prueba a almacenar ese elemento fuera del while y eliminarlo cuando acabe este. Dentro del if unicamente asigna el valor al elemento y rompe el while con un break.

Comment: ¿Te muestra el mensaje "Error" de este `catch`: `catch (Exception e) {System.err.println("Error");}`? Porque en ese caso la variable `e` tendrá la información de la excepción. respecto a la variable `teclado`, ¿podrías poner en tu ejemplo el código completo? Así es más fácil intentar reproducir el error

Comment: PD: Si hay valor de la variable e lo que pasa que no lo estas usando.

Comment: @JDev Jo pues mirando muchos ejemplos, de remove con iteradores toda la gente lo pone asi y les funciona. No entiendo por que a mi no... Podrías ponerme un ejemplo? En la arraylist ya hay articulos metidos, solo quiero que me busque el articulo que inserto por scanner y que lo elimine

Comment: Estas planteando el mismo problema que ayer. No veo qué aportas preguntando dos veces lo mismo.

Comment: **No** pongas `(SOLUCIONADO)`, SOes **no es un foro**. En lugar de ello, vota positivamente las respuestas que te ayudaron, y, si fué alguna de ellas la que resolvió tu problema, **márcala como `aceptada`**.

Answer (score 2):

El "iterador" normal (`Iterator`) no proporciona la utilidad de eliminar elementos. Además, asume que la colección sobre la itera no sufre cambios, y si la colección sufre cambios la siguiente invocación del iterador dara un `ConcurrentModficiationException`.

Hay tres opciones:

1. Creas una lista auxiliar, y con el iterador recorres tu lista original y añades todos los elementos a la nueva lista, excepto los que hay que eliminar. Luego vacías la lista original, e iteras la lista auxiliar añadiendo todos sus elementos a la lista original.
2. La respuesta de MrSman, en que la lista auxiliar es de los elementos a eliminar y se hace `removeAll`. No me acaba de convencer por el `removeAll` del final (si puedes usarlo ¿por qué no usar `remove` directamente?).
3. Usas un `ListIterator` que sí te da las operaciones para eliminar el elemento actual.

Siendo como es un ejercicio, creo que lo te están pidiendo es la solución 1. o 2.

Comment: a mi tampoco se me habría ocurrido usar el removeAll() pero he hecho una prueba y parece que funciona bien. Con usar remove() directamente supongo que habría que iterar sobre otro bucle a no ser que el código sea identificador de los artículos yse tenga la certeza de que sólo va a haber un elemento que coincida.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que están intentando borrar un elemento del iterador cuando en realidad el iterador no es más que un objeto que recorre el ArrayList. Lo que deberías hacer es borrar el elemento del ArrayList, no del iterador. Algo así sería el código:

```
public String borrarArticulo() {
    String codigo = null;
    ArrayList<Articulo> elemToRemove= new ArrayList();

    try {

            System.out.println("Por favor introduzca el codigo del articulo");
            codigo = teclado.nextLine();
            ValidarCodigo(codigo);

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Articulo temp = iter.next();
            if (temp.getCodigo().equals(codigo)) {
                elemToRemove.add(temp);
                System.out.println("Producto eliminado");
            }
        }
        coleccion.removeAll(elemToRemove);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error");
    }
    return codigo;
}
```

De esta forma el remove se aplica sobre el ArrayList.

Si el elemento que quieres borrar es único, es decir, el código introducido sólo corresponde a un artículo, se simplifica aún más:

```
public String borrarArticulo() {
    String codigo = null;
    Articulo toRemove = new Articulo();
    try {

        System.out.println("Por favor introduzca el codigo del articulo");
        codigo = teclado.nextLine();
        ValidarCodigo(codigo);

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Articulo temp = iter.next();
            if (temp.getCodigo().equals(codigo)) {
                toRemove = temp;
                break;
                System.out.println("Producto eliminado");
            }
        }
        coleccion.remove(toRemove);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error");
    }
    return codigo;
}
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Da fallo de exception java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: OJO que no se esta borrando el elemento si no el siguiente que hay 2 `iter.next()`

Comment: @Flowcou prueba a crear una lista con los elementos a borrar y borrarlos fuera del bucle. Tal y como está en la respuesta actualizada. Uso iter.next() porque es lo qye compara en el if entonces entiendo que ese es el elemento a borrar.

Comment: `iter.next()`varia en cada llamada por lo que no vale.

Comment: @JDev a qué te refieres exactamente? Ahí me he perdido..

Comment: @MrSman imagina que el ArrayList tiene n articulos. Cuando haces `iter.next().getCodigo().equals(codigo)`te devuelve el elemento k pero al hacer despues  `elemToRemove.add(iter.next());` te devuelve el elemento k+1

Comment: Entonces podría guardar el iter.next() en una variable temporal y operar con esa variable? Igual así funciona como se quiere @JDev .. actualizo la respuesta para que entiendas a qué me refiero.

Comment: Si, asi si funcionaria.